# Crear usuario Wordress en instalación por función

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, wordpress

Estoy haciendo un script en PHP para hacer un instalador de Wordpress. El problema lo tengo cuando lanzo la función que instala el Wordpress.

He localizado el problema y creo que se da a la hora de crear el usuario.

La función que llama a la instalación es la siguiente:

```
wp_install(
        $installation->wp_sitename,
        $installation->wp_admin_name,
        $installation->wp_admin_email,
        false,
        '',
        $installation->wp_admin_password
    );
```

Al ejecutar la función, el error que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
"message": "Undefined property: WP_Error::$ID",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
    "file": "/user/user_folder/project/clients_folder/wordpress_1_folder/wp-includes/class-wp-user.php",
    "line": 170,
    ...
```

Es curioso porque al consultar en código esa línea, se indica en los comentarios de la función que el ID es opcional.

Función `class-wp-user.php` linea 134

```
if ( $id instanceof WP_User ) {
    $this->init( $id->data, $site_id );
    return;
} elseif ( is_object( $id ) ) {
    $this->init( $id, $site_id );
    return;
}
```

Función `class-wp-user.php` linea 168

```
public function init( $data, $site_id = '' ) {
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->ID   = (int) $data->ID;

    $this->for_site( $site_id );
}
```

Como nota adicional, tengo en el archivo de configuración wp-config.php definido `define('WP_DEBUG', 'true');`

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de encontrar haciendo un seguimiento la solución. El problema está que los nombres de los usuarios han de ser únicos, no puede haber duplicados.

En mi caso, estoy utilizando una misma base de datos para almacenar todas las tablas que genera Wordpress al realizar la instalación, cambiando el prefijo de las mismas para distinguir a que instalación de wordpress pertenece.

Al hacer la llamada:

```
wp_install(
    $installation->wp_sitename,

    //Este nombre ha de ser único
    $installation->wp_admin_name, 

    $installation->wp_admin_email,
    false,
    '',
    $installation->wp_admin_password
);
```

Extraño aunque se trate de tablas diferentes.